# Is there a way to read characters from an .exe process? (A game, C++)

Tags: c++, windows, ocr

So I want to be able to read the specific x-x and y-y coordinate, defining the word on the screen.
This is the screen, I want to read, and if it says reconnect I wanna do an action based on that condition: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHre9.jpg - this is so I can know if I have been disconnected, and if so I can reconnect, since I know I'm in a disconnected state.

I know I can read image files, with OCR - but can I read from a live process, with no saved .image file, only the live screen to read from?

Regards.

Comment: You can grab a snapshot of a window at any time.

Comment: Here is some code for screen capture on the windows api: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551444/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551444/487892)

Comment: With my above comments if this is a windows application using windows controls you may want to read the text from the control directly. If this is a DirectX or opengl game you may need to look into options of taking screen captures when using DirectX or opengl.